# Equivalent is_constructible to capture protected construction in derived

Tags: c++, traits, sfinae

Like said in the title. 
Would anyone be able to propose an equivalent to std::is_constructible that would succeed in testing construction of an hypothetical derived class using a protected constructor of the tested class?

```
class A {
protected:
     A(int);
};
static_assert(std::is_constructible<A,int>::value,"fails but ok");
static_assert(is_derived_constructible<A,int>::value,"would work");
```